# How to edit start menu in Windows 10 in a way that it doesn't "fall back" on updating Windows or software pieces?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

I'm using Classic Shell, so my experience in restructuring Start Menu is more like in Windows 7: I open `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and edit folders and links there and that is reflected in the Start Menu.

Now, I have a persistent problem with that. Say, I've created a folder `Programs\coding` and put the link to VS Code there – from `Programs\Visual Studio Code` (and deleted that folder). The issue is – that old link comes back – on updating VS Code, as far as I understand. Same thing happens with other programs. Also, on "big" Windows updates a number of "system" links that I've sorted get to their old places.

My guess is, there's some place in registry (or elsewhere) where I can edit the link location and that will prevent such problems. The question is where should I look for it? I've searched registry for "Visual Studio Code" (the name of the folder), but haven't found anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative answer : Such an option does not exist.

Unfortunately, every time that you install a new version for any
software that doesn't ask you where to install its icons,
you will need to move the icons to their new place yourself.

There is no software that I know of that will do it for you.

Comment: Hm, I should probably ask some software author who understands the internals of an installer. Some installers allow to configure the folder (inside Programs) during the installation, which seems to be some system pattern, so they are configurabe in some way, but I haven't found a tool for this as well (although haven't searched *much*)

Comment: I have experience with using such tools for creating installations. This is an option that has to be built into the installer, which includes among others storing the chosen icons folder in the registry (or config file) to be found when the installer is upgrading an existing setup. If the option is not available to start with when installing, then you can't add it in yourself.

Comment: Ah, it's great that you have experitise in this! So there's even no conventions on how such registry entry should be preferrably named, right?

Comment: Right, the developer creating the installation defines the included steps. For the better products, interacting with the user for the icons folder is an additional step while creating the installation. Some helpful products will suggest a default, but the developer is not obliged to follow.